# use sqlalchemy entity isolately

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, entity

i just want to use an entity modify it to show something,but don't want to change to the db,
but after i use it ,and in some other place do the `session.commit()`

it will add this entity to db,i don't want this happen,
any one could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expunge it from session before modifying object, then this changes won't be accounted on next commits unless you add the object back to session. Just call `session.expunge(obj)`.